# List of records that shows system notes in netsuite

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0, suitescript1.0

How to find out list of records that have system notes in netsuite? Please Help!

Is there any way to get list of records which have system notes?

Comment: Can you explain more about what you are trying to do and what you have tried?
SystemNotes are a standard field in Netsuite so pretty much all built-in records have them and you can get at their data via saved searches/the N/search api or via N/query. Or are you trying to find a list of custom record types that have system notes enabled?

Comment: All records in netsuite does not have system notes. So I have to list out only records which have system notes on that record.

Comment: This would be a great deal of work. What I understand is that you want to search for, say transactions, that have no system notes. If hat is correct you can explore using the  `N/query` module to search for all transactions where the id is not in the set of transactions that have system notes. You'd have to do that for each record type.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do something with the help of a saved search on the system notes.

[image]

Comment: I tried this but getting all records from number 1 to n, not getting record wise list.

Answer (score 0):

For getting the record-wise list please Use Available Filters and select the Record Type filter in the saved search.